# Why value is not a member of class in ArrayBuffer[Any]

Tags: scala, class-hierarchy

I've just started learning scala. In classes primary constructor parameters with `val` and `var` are public whereas parameters without `val` or `var` are private values. So, when I'm trying to execute following code, everything should work fine.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

class Cat(val name: String)
class Dog(val name: String)

val dog = new Dog("Harry")
val cat = new Cat("Sally")

val animals = ArrayBuffer.empty[Any]
animals.append(dog)
animals.append(cat)
animals.foreach(pet => println(pet.name))
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:12: error: value name is not a member of scala.this.Any
  animals.foreach(pet => println(pet.name))  // Prints Harry Sally
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: You parametrized ‘ArrayBuffer’ with parameter ‘Any’, so now ‘pet’ is seen by compiler as ‘Any’, but there is no ‘name’ field in ‘Any’. You need common supertype containing ‘name’ for both pets and parametrize ‘ArrayBuffer’ with it instead of’Any’

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayBuffer.empty[Any]` specifies array buffer is storing `Any` values, not `Cat`s and `Dog`s, and `Any` does not know about `name`. Try relating `Cat` and `Dog` via `Animal` trait like so

```
trait Animal {
  val name: String
}
class Cat(val name: String) extends Animal
class Dog(val name: String) extends Animal
```

and then specify the array buffer to store `Animal` like so

```
val animals = ArrayBuffer.empty[Animal]
animals.append(dog)
animals.append(cat)
animals.foreach(pet => println(pet.name))
```

which outputs

```
Harry
Sally
```

Comment: With `ArrayBuffer.empty[Any]` how is `append` able to add `dog` and `cat` ?

Comment: `Any` is the root of the Scala class hierarchy, so `Dog` and `Cat` are automatically `Any`.

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
val animals = ArrayBuffer.empty[Any]
//                              ↑↑↑
```

You explicitly tell Scala that your `animals` `ArrayBuffer` can contain `Any` object. As a result, you can only use methods of `Any` [which are not that many](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html).

It is, for example, perfectly legal to put an `Int` into `animals`, since you told Scala that the contents of `animals` can be anything. However, `Int` doesn't have a `name` method, and thus your code would blow up at runtime if you tried to get the name of an `Int`. In order to prevent your code from blowing up at runtime, Scala rather decides to not allow you to write that code at all in the first place.

So, you need to tell Scala *what* kinds of things you want to put into the `animals`. Unfortunately, we only have two explicit nominal types at our disposal here: `Dog` and `Cat`. However, when you type `animals` as `ArrayBuffer[Dog]`, then you can't put Sally in there, and if you type it as `ArrayBuffer[Cat]`, then you can't put Harry in there.

So, we need to type `animals` as something that allows both `Dog`s and `Cat`s.

In Scala 3, you could use a [*Union Type*](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html):

```
val animals = ArrayBuffer.empty[Dog | Cat]
```

Alas, Scala 3 is still quite far away.

Another way would be to use a [*Compound type with structural refinement*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#compound-types):

```
val animals = ArrayBuffer.empty[{val name: String}]
```

This allows your code to work, but it may not necessarily do what you want: this allows *any object* that has a `val` named `name` of type `String`, not just `Dog`s and `Cat`s. In particular, you could put something in `animals` which is not an animal, as long as it has a name.

The best way would probably be to introduce an abstract supertype (let's call it `Pet`) that defines an abstract `val name` that gets overridden by `Cat` and `Dog`, and then type `animals` as `ArrayBuffer[Pet]`:

```
trait Pet {
  val name: String
}

class Dog(val name: String) extends Pet
class Cat(val name: String) extends Pet

val animals = ArrayBuffer.empty[Pet]
```